Video integration using plyr js and hls js
I'm working to live streaming using AWS server m3u8 format video. I have added an HTML5 video player using plyr.js and hls.js. I want to add a live tag in the control bar if the video is live now. if a random video is placed in the source then the live tag should not come. Also, how can I stop progress bar buffering?
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js"></script>
                <script src="https://unpkg.com/plyr@3"></script>
                <script>
                    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
                        const video = document.querySelector("video");
                        // const unmuteButton = document.getElementById("unmuteButton");
                        const unmuteButton = document.querySelector("button[data-plyr='mute']");
                        // menu.querySelectorAll('button[data-plyr="quality"]')
                        const liveIndicator = document.getElementById("liveIndicator");
                        const source = video.getElementsByTagName("source")[0].src;
                        const defaultQuality = 720;
                        console.log(video)
                        console.log(unmuteButton)
                        // console.log(video.muted)
                        
                        unmuteButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
                            video.muted = false;
                            video.volume = 1.0; 
                            video.autoplay = true;
                            unmuteButton.style.display = "none";
                            document.getElementById("mutebutton").style.display = 'none';
                       });


                        const defaultOptions = {
                            controls: [
                                    'play-large', 'play', 'progress', 'current-time', 'duration', 
                                    'mute', 'volume', 'settings', 'airplay', 'fullscreen'
                                ],
                            settings: ['quality'], 
                            autoplay: true,
                            muted: true,
                            volume : 0,
                            ratio: '16:9',
                            seek: 0,
                        };

                        function getCustomLabel(qualityValue) {
                            const qualityLabels = {
                                1080: 'Full HD (1080p)',
                                720: 'HD (720p)',
                                480: 'SD (480p)',
                                360: 'Low (360p)',
                                240: 'Very Low (240p)'
                            };
                            return qualityLabels[qualityValue] || '';
                        }

                        if (Hls.isSupported()) {
                            const hls = new Hls();
                            hls.loadSource(source);

                            hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function (event, data) {
                                const availableQualities = hls.levels.map((l) => l.height);

                                defaultOptions.quality = {
                                    default: availableQualities[0],
                                    options: availableQualities,
                                    forced: true,
                                    onChange: (e) => updateQuality(e),
                                };

                                const player = new Plyr(video, defaultOptions);

                                // Wait for Plyr instance creation
                                player.on('ready', (event) => {
                                    const plyr = event.detail.plyr;                                    video.muted = true;
                                    video.volume = 0;
                                    unmuteButton.style.display = "block";
                                    console.log(video.volume)
                                    console.log(video.muted)
                                    handleLiveStream(plyr);
                                    // Update quality labels when a quality option is clicked
                                    const qualityMenus = document.querySelectorAll('.plyr__menu__container');
                                    qualityMenus.forEach((menu) => {
                                        if (menu.querySelector('.plyr__menu__value')) {
                                            const qualityButtons = menu.querySelectorAll('button[data-plyr="settings"]');
                                            qualityButtons.forEach((button) => {
                                                button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                                                    updateQualityLabels(player);
                                                });
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                                player.on('enterfullscreen', () => {
                                    handleFullscreenChange();
                                });

                                player.on('exitfullscreen', () => {
                                    handleFullscreenChange();
                                });
                            });

                            hls.attachMedia(video);
                            window.hls = hls;
                        } else {
                            const player = new Plyr(video, defaultOptions);
                            player.on('enterfullscreen', () => {
                                handleFullscreenChange();
                            });

                            player.on('exitfullscreen', () => {
                                handleFullscreenChange();
                            });
                        }
                        function handleFullscreenChange() {
                            if (video.paused) {
                                return;
                            }

                            if (document.fullscreenElement) {
                                // Fullscreen entered
                                rotateScreen();
                            } else {
                                // Fullscreen exited
                                rotateScreen();
                            }
                        }

                        function rotateScreen() {
                            // Simulate orientation changes by forcing reflows
                            // Get the viewport width and height
                            const viewportWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0);
                            const viewportHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0);

                            // Determine the orientation and update styles accordingly
                            const isLandscape = viewportWidth > viewportHeight;
                            if (isLandscape) {
                                // Landscape orientation
                                document.documentElement.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
                                document.documentElement.style.width = '100%'; // Set width to viewport height
                                document.documentElement.style.height = '100%'; // Set height to viewport width
                            } else {
                                // Portrait orientation
                                document.documentElement.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
                                document.documentElement.style.width = '100%';
                                document.documentElement.style.height = '100%';
                                document.documentElement.style.margin = '0'; // Reset margins
                            }

                            // Trigger reflow
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
                            }, 10);
                        }
                        function updateQuality(newQuality) {
                            window.hls.levels.forEach((level, levelIndex) => {
                                if (level.height === newQuality) {
                                    window.hls.currentLevel = levelIndex;
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        function updateQualityLabels(player) {
                            const qualityMenus = document.querySelectorAll('.plyr__menu__container');
                            qualityMenus.forEach((menu) => {
                                if (menu.querySelector('.plyr__menu__value')) {
                                    const qualityButtons = menu.querySelectorAll('button[data-plyr="quality"]');
                                    qualityButtons.forEach((button) => {
                                        const qualityValue = parseInt(button.value, 10);
                                        const customLabel = getCustomLabel(qualityValue);
                                        if (customLabel) {
                                            button.querySelector('span').textContent = customLabel;
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                            
                        }
                        function handleLiveStream(player) {
                            // Customize live stream behavior
                            player.config.live = true;
                            player.config.seekTime = 0; // Disable seeking
                            player.duration = 0; // Set duration to 0 for live

                            // Show live indicator
                            liveIndicator.style.display = 'block';

                            // Hide total duration and set progress to indeterminate
                            const controls = document.querySelector('.plyr__controls');
                            const progress = controls.querySelector('.plyr__progress');
                            const durationElement = controls.querySelector('.plyr__time--duration');

                            if (durationElement) {
                                durationElement.style.display = 'none'; // Hide total duration
                            }

                            if (progress) {
                                const liveIndicatorContainer = document.createElement('div');
                                liveIndicatorContainer.className = 'live-indicator-container';
                                liveIndicatorContainer.appendChild(liveIndicator);

                                // Insert live indicator before the progress bar's parent container
                                 if (controls.children.length > 1) {
                                    controls.insertBefore(liveIndicatorContainer, controls.children[1]);
                                } else {
                                    controls.appendChild(liveIndicatorContainer);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Check if the video is live
                        function isLiveStream() {
                            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(source.split('?')[1]);
                            return urlParams.has('live');
                        }

                        // Display or hide the live button based on the stream type
                        if (isLiveStream()) {
                            liveIndicator.style.display = 'block';
                        } else {
                            liveIndicator.style.display = 'none';
                        }
                    });
                </script>


                <div id="player">
                    <video autoplay muted playsinline poster="<?php echo $vimeo_poster ?>">
                        <source type="application/x-mpegURL" src="https://3d26876b73d7.us-west-2.playback.live-video.net/api/video/v1/us-west-2.913157848533.channel.rkCBS9iD1eyd.m3u8">
                    </video>
                </div>
                
                <div id="mutebutton" style="<?php if(empty($data['webcast_embed_code'])){ echo 'display:none;'; } ?>">
                    <button type="button" id="unmuteButton" class="custom-button plyr__control--pressed" aria-label="Unmute" data-plyr="mute">Click here to Unmute</button>
                </div>
                <div id="liveIndicator" class="live-indicator" style="display: none;">
                    LIVE
                </div> 
                <style type="text/css">
                    /* Hide the buffer bar */
                    .plyr__progress__buffer {
                        display: none !important;
                    }
    
                    /* Ensure the progress bar takes up the full width */
                    .plyr__controls {
                        max-width: 100% !important;
                    }
    
                    /* Style the played progress bar */
                    .plyr__progress--played {
                        background: red; /* Change the color as needed */
                        height: 100%; /* Ensure it covers the full height of the progress bar */
                    }
    
                    /* Style the live indicator */
                    .live-indicator {
                        background: red;
                        color: white;
                        padding: 0px 6px;
                        /* font-weight: bold; */
                        border-radius: 3px;
                        margin-right: 10px;
                        font-size: 13px;
                    }
                </style>

